# Night-threaders

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In 'The Sandman - Vol.3 - The Dream Country' by Neil Gaiman chapter 2, a cat says to another cat: 'Well-met, fellow **night-threaders**'
Do you know what does 'night-threaders' mean in this context?

Comment: Given that cats have reputations for being graceful, agile, and particularly silent in their motion (as well as being crepuscular, which is next door to nocturnal), it's possible Gaiman was creating the imagery of the cats [*threading*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Thread&ls=a) their way through the night. (If you have trouble identifying the relevant definition of *threading* in that link, it's the ones which mean "*Move carefully or skillfully in and out of obstacles*").

Comment: You were wonderful!! Thank you so much! I think your explanation makes totally sense,

Answer (score 1):

This is **the only threading** the cats are mentioned to do, from what I could find:

> The Counsellor: Gillian Jackson - 2011
>
> 'Hello Beautiful,' Chloe said as **the cat threaded herself around the
>   little girl's legs**, making her giggle with pleasure.

So, my question to the OP is, what are the cats in this book known to do at night? The book is not showing up at Google Books, nor is this passage.

Comment: I think Dan Bron's comment answers the question, but thank you anyway for your answer!

Comment: You haven't answered my question about what those cats are described to be doing a night.

Comment: They are simply walking towards a kind of cat's meeting to listen a cat talking.